# Request in Flask from a Form in HTML is returning None Value, What should I Do?

Tags: python, html, flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2

I am getting no value on request in flask. It is returning None value.

I have tried changing the method but no use.

The flask code:

```
@app.route("/login/user/book")
def searchbook():

    bookname=request.form.get("search")

    return render_template("message.html",heading=bookname ,message=" ")
```

The webpage:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block heading %}Welcome to BookSarkar{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<p>Welcome {{ name }}</p>

<form action="{{ url_for('searchbook') }}" method="get" class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto" placeholder="Search books">
        <p style="text-align:center;">
            <button type ="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 mx-auto">Search</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="fixed-top m-2">
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}" role="button" style="float:right;">Log out</a>
</div>  
{% endblock %}
```

The message webpage:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block heading %}{{ heading }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

{{ message }}
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url_for('index') }}" role="button">Return to Home Page</a>

{% endblock %}
```

The layout page has no bugs as all other pages are working fine. I expected the webpage to show the given input but it is showing None

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `return render_template("message.html",heading=bookname ,message=" ")` in your flask code and inspect the value of bookname. Is it None or is it populated?

Comment: @PeterDannemann I am new to this and dont know how to debug, that is why i am using the     return render_template("message.html",heading=bookname ,message=" ")    to test whether it is None or populated

Comment: Ok just put ‘print(bookname)’ before that line. What does it print when you make a request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request.form` contains values submitted via `post` or `put`, while your form uses `get`. Try using  `request.args.get("search")` instead of `request.form.get("search")`